# вместо нужных значений выводится какой-то бред. Помогите, пожалуйста

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int N, A, B, i, j, sum;
    std::cin >> N >> A >> B;
    int *abarray = new int[N+1];
    abarray[0] = A;
    abarray[1] = B;
    for (i=2; i <= N - 2; i++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            sum += abarray[j];
        }
        abarray[i] += sum;
    }
    for (int i = N; i>=0; i--) std::cout << abarray[i] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @EOF, полезный совет, однако положение это не спасает

Comment: вы считаете сумму элементов **вместе** с тем, которого должны были вычислить. `for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) sum += abarray[j];` В задаче сказано , что должна быть сумма **предыдущих**. Добавляете к мусорнуму значения памяти ещё и сумму `abarray[i] += sum;`. А надо было просто делать присвоение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так сойдет?

```
int main()
{
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    int *abarray = new int[N];
    std::cin >> abarray[0] >> abarray[1];
    for (int i = 2, k = 1, m = abarray[0] + abarray[1];
         i < N; i++, k*=2) abarray[i] = m*k;
    for (int i = N; i-->0;)
        std::cout << abarray[i] << " ";
}
```

Можно и без массива и с одним циклом:

```
int main()
{
    int N, A, B;
    std::cin >> N >> A >> B;
    B += A;
    N = (1 << (N-3))*B;
    for(;N != B;N >>= 1) std::cout << N << " ";
    std::cout << B << " " << B-A << " " << A;
}
```

Comment: а хотя стоп, прога тупо складывает предыдущее значение дважды, хотя должна сложить все предыдущие :^

Comment: Пропишите какой-нибудь пример руками и посмотрите, есть ли ошибка. Например, 5 1 2. Элементы: 1 2 3 6 12. Так? Т.е. вывод 12 6 3 2 1. Смотрим: https://ideone.com/zNnW2f Что не так?

Comment: это я уже понял, как только можно будет, так и поставлю) а, хотя да, извиняюсь, тупанул

Comment: окей, попробую...